# Issue with onchange as a part of jquery mobile select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am unable to get selected value as a part of select menu, My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#select-choice-1').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
    })
</script>
```

How can I get the value onChange function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function() {...});` to make sure your DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select-choice-1').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
    })
});
```

For jQuery mobile, it's better to use **[pagecreate](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)** event:

> Triggered when the page has been created in the DOM (via ajax or
>   other) and after all widgets have had an opportunity to enhance the
>   contained markup.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {
    $('#select-choice-1').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
    })
});
```

Comment: It is working fine. Is is possible to loop inside the function, I mean My select menu values are coming dynamically from database. How can I insert values from sqliteDB. Please any suggestions

Comment: It's Okay. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QvG2R/1/

Use following syntax

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {

      alert( this.value );
    });
```

Comment: I created fiddle , did you test it?